# Requirement in Visualforce and apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

We have total 9 steps, In step 4 : We have some check box options like A, B, C, D , E, F, G.

We have selected A B C D

In that we have two fields like unit level (text) and service level (Pick list).

Here A and C have same field optionns selected.

In Step 5 : It will display like buttons A B C D

In A  and C have same field options

What is the requirement here is : If I click A, some options will display. Those options have check box options. If I select some check box options…..
automatically selected C options because of same option fiels we selected in step 4.

Please tell me solution for this ?

Comment: Hi Vivek, what have you tried so far? Are there any specific problems that you encountered when implementing a solution?